# set filtered output as variable in cmd

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd

I have a command (using adb) that outputs to the screen this line:

> ```
> * Record 232: Record {AAAAAA #999 Alpha.Beta.Gamma US=1 JP=1}
> ```

This is a filtered output (such as `dir | findstr ...`).

I need to find a way to save this line as a string (`set _var`...) and to be able to manipulate it later (need to isolate only the `Alpha.Beta.Gamma` part).

I've tried:

```
for /F %%a in ('dir | findstr file') do set _var=%%a
```

All it does is set `_var` to `%7` for some reason..

Comment: I don't understand the question. What has the string "* Record 232: etc" got to do with the command "dir | findstr" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with :

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b ^| findstr "file"') do set _var=%%a
```

pipe needs to be escaped in this case.

Comment: this results in
"%%a was unexpected at this time."

Comment: @Ragnarok - if you execute this from command line you need single `%` instead of double.

Comment: @Ragnarok - now you can accept the answer and get some points.